# Error with Firebase Each provider can only be set once. phone was set twice

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm watching a tutorial on how to make a Kotlin android app
I keep getting an error: `Each provider can only be set once. phone was set twice.`

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {     **// line 18**

companion object{
    private val LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 7171
}
private lateinit var providers: List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> // lateinit = we will give it a value later.
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var listener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener


override fun onStart(){
    super.onStart()
    delaySplashScreen()
}

override fun onStop(){
    if(firebaseAuth !=null && listener !=null) firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    super.onStop()

}
private fun delaySplashScreen() {

    Completable.timer(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS,AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener)})
    // it was used to be inside .subscribe
    // Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity, "Splacsh screen Run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    init()
}
private fun init() {
    providers = Arrays.asList(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()

    )

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { myFirebaseAuth ->
        val user = myFirebaseAuth.currentUser
        if (user != null)
            Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity, "Welcome: "+user.uid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else
            showLoginLayout()     **//line 64**
    }
}

private fun showLoginLayout() {
    val authMethodPickerLayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout.Builder(R.layout.layout_sing_in)
            .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.btn_phone_sign_in)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_google_sign_in)
            .build()


    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authMethodPickerLayout)
                    .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)    **//line 80**
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .build()
            , LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE){
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity, ""+response!!.error!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    }
}
```

the error i'm getting

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each provider can only be set once. phone was set twice.
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI$AuthIntentBuilder.setAvailableProviders(AuthUI.java:1301)
    at com.example.alaaalddrbapp.SplashScreenActivity.showLoginLayout(SplashScreenActivity.kt:80)
    at com.example.alaaalddrbapp.SplashScreenActivity.access$showLoginLayout(SplashScreenActivity.kt:18)
    at com.example.alaaalddrbapp.SplashScreenActivity$init$1.onAuthStateChanged(SplashScreenActivity.kt:64)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.zzj.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzj.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:6)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I'm using these dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
```

As i'm kinda new in programming I would love if you can give more details on answers, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An auth provider is "thing" that a user can sign in with in your app. So you may have an email+password provider, a Facebook provider, and a phone number provider.

FirebaseUI can sign in with many providers, but in its UI each provider can be present only once.

You're trying to set the same auth provider twice here:

```
providers = Arrays.asList(
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()

)
```

My guess is that you wanted to show another provider on the second line.

Either way, this will work (to sign in only with a phone num ber):

```
providers = Arrays.asList(
    AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()
)
```

As will this (to allow signing in with email+password and/or a phone number):

```
providers = Arrays.asList(
    AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
    AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem.